# C# issue with list .add()

Tags: c#, list

I have a class:

```
ProductData ProductData = new ProductData();
```

and created a list:

```
List<ProductData> ProductDataList = new List<ProductData>();
```

when I add items to the list as so:

```
ProductDataList.Add(ProductData);
```

the last element in the list is overwriting all previous elements, I am not sure why this is happening, can anyone help?

here is more of the structure:

```
ProductData ProductData = new ProductData();

List<ProductData> ProductDataList = new List<ProductData>();

while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    ProductData.value = “some values I am assigning go here”;

          ProductDataList.Add(ProductData);
       };
```

Comment: Where does the `ProductData` variable come from? Please post the entire block of code.

Comment: Why does this have a -1? Honestly, I feel like people slap a -1 on people they think are stupid instead of actually evaluating the quality of the question.

Comment: @TheBuzzSaw  why does this question have a +1? Honestly, I feel like people slap a +1 on posts that look well formatted instead of actually evaluating the question

Comment: @TheBuzzSaw It is impossible to know for certain exactly what is happening in this question without making guesses and assumptions.  The OP has not shown us the code that is actually causing the problem, rather he's only showing us 3 select lines with absolutely 0 context.  Apparently he's has multiple Add statements, when he's adding to the list, but we don't see how those multiple `Add` statements are executed.

Comment: Please edit the question rather than posting all of the code in a comment.

Comment: @SamIam So first, an obnoxious mirror response to my question, and then an admission that you were unable to deduce what the problem was. Obviously, it was enough information for Servy and I to immediately spot the problem. The author posted enough context to find the problem.

Comment: @TheBuzzSaw  Servy did rely on an assumption for his answer, as it turns out he did guess right, but look at the enormous difference in clarity between how the question was initially and how it is now after the context was added.  As it turns out, the context made a **gigantic** difference in the clarity of the question

Answer (score 9):

You're not creating multiple new `ProductData` instances, instead your mutating the same instance over and over again.

You almost certainly want to just move the line: `ProductData ProductData = new ProductData();` from outside of your loop to inside of it.  That will ensure that you create N instances, not one.

Comment: +1 This question is a fundamental misunderstanding of C# references, not an issue with the List or its Add method.

Comment: thank you very much, this solved my issue.  I am very much still a beginner and this helped!

Answer (score 1):

I bet that your full code must be something like this:

```
ProductData ProductData = new ProductData(); 
ProductData.Something = "1st";

ProductDataList.Add(ProductData);

ProductData.Something = "1st";

ProductDataList.Add(ProductData);

ProductData.Something = "2nd";

ProductDataList.Add(ProductData);

ProductData.Something = "3rd";

ProductDataList.Add(ProductData);
```

And you say that it's overwriting because all of them have the value of "3rd".
It's not an issue with the list, it's with your **object instance**.

Note that you've created only one instance, it's that `new ProductData` over there. When you change it, you're not creating new instances, but simply changing your only instance.

You should create new instances for each object you have.